# I have a Compaq computer from 2000

Tags: display, sleep

I have an old computer try to pull off information on it that when I plug in a monitor it turns on then states going into sleep mode computer stays on ?? HELP PLEASE

Comment: Sounds to me like the video card from the computer is bad, and not providing signal to the monitor. Or that the monitor is looking at the wrong connection (DVI when it should be looking at VGA, most likely). What kind of video connector does the computer have?

Comment: It’s probably an IDE hard drive. You can use a USB to IDE adapter or an external USB/IDE hard drive enclosure by removing the hard drive from the computer and plugging it in to another system. You could probably avoid the trouble by just calling around to some local repair shops who would probably do it for you for a small fee. The old computer itself is pretty useless and you shouldn’t waste time or money trying to fix that. All you want is the hard drive out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Monitors go into sleep when the monitor receives a "power save" signal from the computer, or when no signal at all is received.

Standard trouble shooting steps:

- Try turning everything off and on again.
- Try unplugging all connections (power, monitor, keyboard, etc.), then plugging it all back in.
- Try another monitor on that computer.
- Try that monitor on another computer.
- Try turning off the computer, start tapping F8 on the keyboard continuously, and then turn the computer on.  Continue tapping F8 until you get a menu, or the monitor goes into sleep mode.  If you get a menu, look for an option for "Safe Mode", "Base Video", or "VGA Mode".